# set user date when user first time login into the system Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x .. i have a field in my users table called "logindate".. i am setting a date .but dont know why it is not saving the date into users table against the user who is currently first time login into the system ..here is my code of UsersController.

```
   public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow('index');
    $this->Security->requireSecure('login');// for security

    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Authenticate.Cookie' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'userModel' => 'User',

        ),
        'Authenticate.MultiColumn' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'columns' => array('email', 'mobileNo'),
            'userModel' => 'User',
        )
    );
  }

public function index(){
    $this->layout='logindefault';

    if (!$this->Auth->login() || !$this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        $this->redirect('/users/login');

    }else {
        $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');
    }

}


public function login() {

    $this->layout='logindefault';
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Account Login');


    if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Userinfo', 'action' => 'gettingstarted'));
        //$this->redirect('/users/dashboard');
    }else{

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

         //here i am saving the date
           $this->request->data['User']['lastLogin'] = date('y-m-d h:i:s');

            $mobileNo=$this->request->data['User']['email'];


            $pos = strpos($mobileNo,'@');
            if($pos){

            }else {

                $mystr=substr($mobileNo,0,1);
                if ($mystr!='+'){
                    $mobileNo = '+'.$mobileNo;
                }
            }
            $this->request->data['User']['email'] = $mobileNo;




            if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn() ) {
                if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){

                    $this->_setCookie($this->Auth->user('idUser'));
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Userinfo', 'action' => 'gettingstarted'));
                }
            }else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect Email/Password Combination');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for testing i change the datatype in db of **lastLogin** to **varchar** and hardcorded the value like this

```
     $this->request->data['User']['lastLogin'] = "hello";
```

still it didnt work...dont know why it is not saving into db against the user id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but dont know why it is not saving the date into users table

You are not calling save anywhere in your login function.